# How do I align my input under my H1

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to align my input to be under my h1 which is inside my div `main`. The H1 is currently vertically and horizontally centered using flexbox and the input inherits the same properties. When I try to add display: inline; and   `display: inline-flex;`, the input box still is not underneath the H1 and is to the right of it.

How do I make my input underneath my current H1 while also maintaining being inside my `<div class="main">`

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.main {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: -1;
}

.main-h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Secret Code';
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 70px;
}

input {
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>BackGround Color</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  <script src="colors.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function takeinput() {
      var input = document.getElementById('user').value;
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = input;
    }
  </script>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="main-h1">Full Screen BackGround Color</div>
    <input type="text" name="enter" class="enter" id="user" value="" />
    <input type="button" value="click" onclick="takeinput();" />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `flex-direction: column;` inside of your `.main` class definition.

Here's a codepen to show you what I mean:
[Codepen Example of Flexbox's flex-direction property](https://codepen.io/ctrlaltdylan/pen/KoBMwE?editors=1100)